# Refresh build definition process parameter custom type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, workflow, tfsbuild

I am using a custom process parameter for a build which is a simple enumerator. That enumerator is located in my repository as a library and referenced in the Workflow arguments. That dll is imported from my repository (import tab of the workflow) and everything should work fine.

The strange thing is that every time I change the enumerator, compile the dll and check-in it, somehow it still keeps the previous old version as a kind of cache and I have no idea of how to refresh it. I change the version of the dll every time just in case with no success. If I take a look at the repository dll by reflector it contains the last version of the new enumerator. Does anyone know how to refresh it in order to show the last version into the build definition process parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out restarting Visual Studio. It was the only way to refresh that source of data, due to other ways didn't work (Team explorer refresh button, check-in the workflow and library, etc).

I realized of that when other group member was able to see the last enumeration on its machine. I don't know whether there is a better way to solve it or not, but this workaround is a bit frustrating...